# Apache Phoenix API for PHP

Tags: php, apache, hbase, apache-phoenix

I want to use Apache Phoenix and retrieve data from Hbase database. I found an API for Phoenix in Java [here](https://phoenix.apache.org/faq.html), But I use PHP for my project and I couldn't find any Phoenix API for PHP. Is there any Phoenix API for PHP ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually ODBC is the way you would use a database with PHP (I am stating the obvious I know :) ).  There are jdbc bridges but we did not have any luck with them.

http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/

We built an ODBC driver at Splice Machine (Open Source) to handle this issue.

You can check it out under ODBC Driver via this link.

http://community.splicemachine.com/

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do if you really, really want to use a language like PHP, is set up a thin API using Apache Thrift that services a PHP client (and any other supported language). Your server would run in Java (native JDBC driver connecting to Apache Phoenix).